# PDO Use value null when insert instead of empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How I can tell PDO to insert NULL instead of an empty value ?

Example :

```
        $SQL = 'INSERT INTO `Calendars_Events` (`CalendarID`, `AccID`, `DateFrom`, `DateTo`, `Location`, `Title`, `Description`)
                VALUES (:CalendarID, :AccID, :From, :To, :Location, :Title, :Description)';

        $Query = $this->DB->Link->prepare($SQL);
        $Query->bindParam(':CalendarID',        $CalendarID,        PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $Query->bindParam(':AccID',             $this->Account->ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $Query->bindParam(':From',              $From,              PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $Query->bindParam(':To',                $To,                PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $Query->bindParam(':Location',          $Location,          PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $Query->bindParam(':Title',             $Title,             PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $Query->bindParam(':Description',       $Description,       PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $Query->execute();
```

If `Location` is empty, it will insert nothing (empty, so '') instead of NULL.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass in `null` instead of the empty `$Location` string, in case the string is empty:

```
empty($Location) ? null : $Location;
```

Comment: Ok, hmm so I have to tell php first that the value is null instead of empty ? I tought MySQL / PDO was doing that on INSERT

Comment: @DavidBélanger, well, if you pass it an empty string, it has no way of knowing that you actually want a `NULL` instead of an empty string... An empty string is a perfectly reasonable value, so it doesn't replace that with `NULL` on its own.

Comment: That is true... it is perfectly legit ! Thanks a lot, of corse, it is working !